# Using both Vaadin and Spring WebFlux in a Spring application, how can I set up routes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin, spring-webflux

I am starting a new web application using Spring Boot 2.0. I would like to use Vaadin 8 to provide the UI. In addition, I'd like to provide an API interface using the WebFlux framework Spring 5 provides.

However, it seems that the act of including Vaadin in my build.gradle causes my WebFlux routes to be ignored:

```
    compile('com.vaadin:vaadin-spring-boot-starter')
```

When I have Vaadin configured, I see it presumably configuring itself on startup:

```
2017-09-16 16:04:52.332  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Registering Vaadin servlet
2017-09-16 16:04:52.333  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Servlet will be mapped to URLs [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.356  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Setting servlet init parameters
2017-09-16 16:04:52.356  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [productionMode] = [false]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.357  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [resourceCacheTime] = [3600]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.357  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [heartbeatInterval] = [300]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.357  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.v.s.b.i.VaadinServletConfiguration     : Set servlet init parameter [closeIdleSessions] = [false]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.441  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-09-16 16:04:52.444  INFO 19413 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'springVaadinServlet' to [/vaadinServlet/*, /VAADIN/*]
```

When I remove Vaadin, I see my WebFlux routes being configured:

```
2017-09-16 16:07:51.434  INFO 19441 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.r.f.s.s.RouterFunctionMapping      : Mapped (Accept: [application/json] && /api) -> /document -> org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction$$Lambda$203/43414926@76ae76e8
```

I do not see this with Vaadin active. It seems like the Vaadin Spring Boot starter package is overriding everything.

I tried changing the path of my @SpringUI components to not be at the root, but that didn't change anything.

I also tried this:

```
@WebServlet(value = "/myspringuis/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class MySpringServlet extends SpringVaadinServlet {
}
```

I do not understand how SpringVaadinServlet fits into this exactly, but suspect it's related to my problem.

Is it possible to have both Vaadin and WebFlux in use at the same time? I would like to separate the routes, obviously, and have WebFlux handle /api/* and Vaadin handle everything else.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Vaading starter for Spring Boot 2 yet. Spring Boot 2.0 isn't final (nor are any of the Spring projects it uses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vaadin-spring-boot-starter` is most likely bringing `spring-boot-starter-web` (which brings a Servlet container and configures Spring MVC).

You can't have both Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux configured in the same application.

Comment: Why not? I haven't tried, but if you have each of them in different sub-URIs, it should work.

Comment: Because Spring Boot is explicitly forbidding that: both have different server runtime models and are not expected to run on the same JVM.